# Atalho no Delphi para mover bloco de código

Tags: delphi

No eclipse tem um atalho que aumenta muito minha produtividade: No editor de código, para mover para linhas acima ou abaixo um bloco de código usa-se por padrão ALT+ Key DOWN/UP. No Delphi, já procurei na [documentação](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts) da Embarcadero e não encontrei correspondente à essa funcionalidade. Também uso o componentes CNpack e GExpert que têm atalhos adicionais, mas, nenhum com essa funcionalidade. Será que aguém conhece o atalho nativo ou não para isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o ModelMaker vc pode utilizar Alt + Shift + DOWN/UP

Comment: Não há este atalho no GExperts. Executa o comando padrão do Delphi vide: http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?ide_enhancements.html

Comment: o que o Alt + Shift + UP/DOWN fez no seu editor? Qual a versão do Delphi?

Comment: Delphi XE5 Version 19.0.14356.6604. A ação que executa é a da documentação do delphi. "Alt+Shift+Up Arrow Moves the cursor up one line and selects the column from the left of the starting cursor position
Alt+Shift+Down Arrow Moves the cursor down one line and selects the column from the left of the starting cursor position". Obs: os Atalhos do Gexperts na aba "Editor Experts" não estão desabilitados.

Comment: Realmente @AnselmoMS, a ferramenta que adiciona essa funcionalidade para mim é o ModelMaker. Editei a resposta

Comment: o ModelMaker é muito caro por um atalho, Obrigado. Incrível como uma ferramenta gratuita como o Eclipse tem tantos atalhos para facilitar a vida do programador e uma ferramenta tão cara como o delphi vem sem 'acessórios'!